# Google Charts - Labelling the Y Axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization

I'm trying to produce a simple Line Chart using Google Charts.

I want to add a `$` sign to the Y axis and a Y axis title, these are cosmetic changes only, not changes to the scale of the axis.

I'm using the `drawChart()` function to achieve this. I'm not overly familiar with JavaScript and there is a considerable amount of documentation online which is slightly confusing to follow given the many ways you can use Google Charts.

What would I need to add to the following code to achieve the Y axis values.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1", { packages:["corechart"] });  
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Date', 'Spend'],
            ['<? echo $dates[ 7 ] ?>',  1000],
            ['<? echo $dates[ 6 ] ?>',  2000],
            ['<? echo $dates[ 5 ] ?>',  3000],
            ['<? echo $dates[ 4 ] ?>',  1000],
            ['<? echo $dates[ 3 ] ?>',  6000],
            ['<? echo $dates[ 2 ] ?>',  8000],
            ['<? echo $dates[ 1 ] ?>',  5000],
        ]);     

        var options = {
            title: 'Spend over the last 7 days',
            colors: ['#f15a29'],
        };
    }  
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Label the vAxis and change the format to include a $:

```
var options = {
    'vAxis': { title: 'Title Here', format:'$#' },
};
```

Format the input so tooltops reflect the $:

```
var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    prefix: '$'
});

formatter.format(data, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var options = {
      title: 'Spend over the last 7 days',
      hAxis: {title: 'Spend($)', titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}
    };
```

Add hAxes to define horizontal axes and vAxes to define vertical axes.
for more infromation refer....
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery

Answer (score 0):

Set the vAxis.title option to set the title and the vAxis.format option to specify the formatting used for the values of the axis:

```
var options = {
    colors: ['#f15a29'],
    vAxis: {
        title: 'Spend over the last 7 days ($)',
        format: '$#,###' // format 3000 as "$3,000"
    }
}
```